# Receiving an error Python 2.7.8 when using code %matplotlib inline

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

When I use the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

I receive an error message saying

```
UsageError: Invalid GUI request u'inline', valid ones are:['osx','qt4', 'glut', 'gtk3', 'pyglet', 'wx','none', 'qt', None,'gtk','tk']
```

I'm running Python `2.7.8` in Anaconda `2.1.0` on Windows 8 64 bit.

Comment: what version of ipython?  `inline` only works in the notebook and qtconsole.

Comment: I'm using IPython 2.2.0